# different results with printf and fprintf

Tags: c++, unix, printf

I need function that prints "word=n" (where n in [0..10]) to stream using linux function `ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);`. Trying to use fprintf, but it's give strange results : program prints in ~1% of calls "woword=n", and `length` for example "woword=7" are 7. Printf print all right. I'm doing something wrong or this is the bag ?

```
if ((id_result = open( out , O_WRONLY)) <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s : %s\n", currentDateTime().c_str(), "could not open output\0");
        ret = P_STREAMS_LOAD_ERROR;
    } 

    void printProbability( int probability ){
      char buf[50];
      memset( buf, '\0', 50 );
      int length = sprintf( buf, "word=%i\n\0", probability );
      fprintf(stderr, "debug : word=%i len = %i\n\0", probability, length );
      int result = write( id_result, buf, length );
      if( result == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s : %s\n", currentDateTime().c_str(), "error \n"); 
      }
    }
```

EDITED:

how I understand, we have 2 theorys :
1) mixing printf and write
2) using '\0' and '\n' in fprintf

```
int length = sprintf( buf, "word=%i", probability );
int result = write( id_result, buf, length );
write( id_result, "\n", 1 );
```

with this code I still have same errors

aa help me :))

Comment: Your C++ code looks a lot like C. If you'd use C++'s classes for strings, streams, files, etc. you probably wouldn't have this problem. Nor any of the host of problems you're bound to run into.

Comment: No need to put `\0` at the end of your strings, the compiler adds it automatically.

Comment: You're mixing line-buffered and non-line-buffered I/O.

Comment: Problem not in '\0'.
Can I print to pipe using c++ ?

Paul can you explain ?)

Comment: The `\0` comment had nothing to do with the problem, I was just pointing out that it's redundant. I'm not sure I understand the exact nature of your problem, I can't see how your code would produce incorrect output unless `buf` was too short.

Comment: I have outputs like "woword=1" , so no, this is not too short buffer :(
Maybe you can advise another way to print results to pipe in this style  ?

Comment: That means something *before* this is printing `"wo"`.

Comment: yes, you are right ! I had write( id_result, buf, length ); with wrong length in another place, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are interspersing calls to `printf` (or `write`) and `fprintf(stderr, ...)` the output won't necessarily come out in order. There is buffering going on, and the actual output probably won't switch at the end-of-line character.

Comment: Hmm. I thought `stdout` and `stderr` usually use the same buffer, and  stay sync'ed.

Comment: But I was added fprintf to debug error :/
Without fprintf I'm still have same error

Comment: @RSahu how could that be? They might be redirected to different places.